# .NET Core in Docker container timeouts when querying the MariaDB Server on the host network

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, docker-container, docker-network

We are running a .NET Core 7 application in a Docker container on Linux Ubuntu. When querying the MariaDb server on the host network, it works fine for 1-2 requests and then it times out. The first 1-2 requests take unusually long.

- The following configured connection-string works, the host RBDMS server can be reached (data is seeded):

  ```
  Server=host.docker.internal,3306;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Max Pool Size=200;
  ```
- This is how we start the container

  ```
  docker run -d --restart unless-stopped -p 5055:80 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --name xx-container xx
  ```

I have read that maybe the docker container is doing unnecessary DNS requests. But I think that should be solved by accessing the hosts network as above.

The application's `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /App

COPY . ./

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build-env /App/out .
ENV DOTNET_EnableDiagnostics=0
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xx.dll"]
```

I tried running the container with `--network=host` and use `localhost` in the connection string, but that disables my configured ports.

Comment: What if to configure Maria to listen all/specific network interfaces and feed that specific interface of the host to connection string?

Comment: @ryan The thing is, the connection can be established, some requests even go through in 200ms. But others take 15-20 Seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by correcting the db connection strings as following:

### The original connection string:

Server=x.x.x.x,3306;Database=xx;User ID=xx;Password=xx;Max Pool Size=50;connect timeout=100;

### The new connection string:

server=host.docker.internal;Port=3306;Database=x;uid=stingray;Password=x;Max Pool Size=50;connect timeout=100;